# Golang DNS resolution not working

Tags: networking, go, dns, network-programming

I'be been reading a lot but I just can't find a solution.

I opened a VPS in Google Cloud, started an instance with Ubuntu and runned a web server i've written in Go listening in port 80. I also registered a domain in my country www.crosslogic.com.ar which delegated like this:

```
n1.crosslogic.com.ar    130.211.196.55
n2.crosslogic.com.ar    130.211.196.55
```

(Two were required but I only had one IP)

When I type the IP in the browser everything everything works fine, but when I try to reach the server using www.crosslogic.com.ar, or crosslogic.com.ar, or n1.crosslogic.com.ar I get ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED.

I did this test intodns.com/crosslogic.com.ar to check the folowing errors:

```
-Missing nameservers reported by your nameservers. You should already know that your NS records at your nameservers are missing, so here it is again:
ns2.crosslogic.com.ar.
ns1.crosslogic.com.ar.

-No valid SOA record came back!

-ERROR: I could not get any A records for www.crosslogic.com.ar!
(I only do a cache request, if you recently added a WWW A record, it might not show up here.)
```

This is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    // Genero un html con los detalles del calculo.


    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    temp, err := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = temp.Execute(w, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Am I missing any configuration in Linux? Those NS Records, A records and SOA is something I need to configure in my server? Shoudln't http/net be handling this stuff? Why request don't reach my port 80?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with your code. Your DNS is not registered properly. When running `nslookup` I get the following:

```
$ nslookup n1.crosslogic.com.ar

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.

$ nslookup n2.crosslogic.com.ar

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
```

Comment: When you say "your DNS" you mean I must install something like BIND in my server or is an issue related to the domain registration?